# Add a node to specific key xml using sed

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sed, sh

I am trying to edit the XML file using sed. Here is the file content which I am trying to edit.

```
<configuration key="student1">
   <list>
     <value>abc</value>
     <value>def</value>
   </list>
</configuration>
```

I want to add the following value to the existing node by comparing the key value.

```
<configuration key="student1">
    <list>
      <value>abc</value>
      <value>NEWVALUE</value>
      <value>def</value>
    </list>
</configuration>
```

How can I achieve it using the sed command? After going to lot of posts, xmlstarlet is the best one to edit the xml files. but I am not able to install due to permission issue. Can someone help me for the solution?

***Update:***

What I have tried is :

```
sed -i "s/\<\list\>/ \<value\> NEWVALUE\<\/VALUE\>/" xmlfile
```

This is not working as expected, its replacing the **list** tag with the NEWVALUE. But I need to compare the key value, then traverse through the lists, then add the new value.

Comment: add the sed code you tried... SO is about helping you with code you already tried and got stuck...

Comment: There's likely to be a way to install whatever you want in your home directory. Sed (or any other text processing program) is definitely not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Sundeep, I have added the code which I tried.

Comment: @BasilJose what you tried is nowhere close to what you want.. you are simply trying to replace `<list>` tag.. and `\<` and `\>` having special meaning of matching word boundaries in GNU sed... what is the key value you want to compare? `student1` or `<value>abc</value>`? in any case, using `sed` here is really not the best idea

Answer (score 1):

If you are desperate and the order of the values isn't important you could use sed and insert the value before the closing list tag and so:

```
sed -r '/\<\list\>/ i\ \t<value>NEWVAL</value>' xmlfile
```

Search the the closing list tag and then enter the value tags along with the NEWVAL value.

Comment: Its not working. :( I tried with `sed -i "s/\<\list\>/ \<value\> NEWVALUE\<\/VALUE\>/" xmlfile`

Comment: It wouldn't as you have remove the "i\" to insert a new line. The -i at the at the beginning simply commits any changes to the file.